# Como llenar array con un ciclo for

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy usando una libreria de **jquery** [DDslick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) para llenar los input selects con estilos inncluso imagenes, la libreria usa arrays para llenarlos por ejemplo..

```
var data= 
      [
       { text: "Facebook",//este es el texto que se ve en la cabecera 
         value: 1,//este es el valor de el select,puedes poner el que quieras
         selected: false//opccion si deceas que este seleccionado o no
       }
      ]
```

este **div** seria el emulador del select

```
<div id="Dropdown"></div><!--este seria el emulador del select-->
```

y asi seria como llenaria ese div para que sea un **select**

```
$('#Dropdown').ddslick({
    data:data,//esta es la variable data que llenara el div
    width:300,//manipular estilos del select 
    selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){//este metodo serai el onchange
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```

esta es la [Documentacion](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) de la libreria por si les interesa

ahora bien lo que yo quiero hacer es llenar un array con fechas de un siclo `for` por que escribir fechas desde el **1970** al **2020** una por una en un array no seria muy gracioso de digamos XD, por lo tanto nececito que el array tenga la misma estructura que usa la libreria para que pueda aceptarmelo ojala me entiendan, en este snipper veran los input **selects** con estilos

```js
//Dropdown plugin data
var ddData = [{text:"any",value:"any"}];
// Si el objeto es igual puedes hacer algo así. 
for(var i=1970; i<2020; i++){
   // Tu fecha
   var dataFecha=i;
   // Creas un nuevo objeto.
   var objeto =   {
            // Le agregas la fecha
            fecha: dataFecha,
            text: i,
            value: i,
            selected: false
   }
 
  ddData.push(objeto);
} 

$('#Dropdown').ddslick({
    data:ddData,
    width:300,
     height:300,
    selectText: "vehicle year",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(data){
    
      var d=data.selectedData.value;
      $("#show").html(d)
    }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js" ></script>


<div id="Dropdown"></div>

<div id="show"></div>


<div id="fecha"></div><!--need to fill out this one width date-->
```

lo que me gustaria es llenar ese array con fechas algo mas o menos asi pero la verda es que no se como hacerlo bien por eso recurri a ustedes, espero que me puedadn ayudar gracias!

```
for(var i=1970; i<2020; i++){

   var dataFecha=i;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Si el objeto es igual puedes hacer algo así.
```

```js
    var ddData = [];
    
    for(var i=1970; i<2020; i++){
       // Tu fecha
       var dataFecha=i;
       // Creas un nuevo objeto.
       var objeto =   {
                // Le agregas la fecha
                fecha: dataFecha,
                text: "Foursquare",
                value: 4,
                selected: false,
                description: "Description with Foursquare",
                imageSrc: "http://i.imgur.com/kFAk2DX.png"
       }
      //Lo agregas al array.
      ddData.push(objeto);
    } 
    
    for ( x in ddData) {
        console.log( ddData[x] );
    }
```

```js
   // Si el array ya contiene datos y quieres agregar fechas  puedes 
    // hacer algo como:
    
    var ddData = [
{
    text: "Facebook",
    value: 1,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Facebook",
    imageSrc: "http://i.imgur.com/XkuTj3B.png"
},
{
    text: "Twitter",
    value: 2,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Twitter",
    imageSrc: "http://i.imgur.com/8ScLNnk.png"
},
{
    text: "LinkedIn",
    value: 3,
    selected: true,
    description: "Description with LinkedIn",
    imageSrc: "http://i.imgur.com/aDNdibj.png"
},
{
    text: "Foursquare",
    value: 4,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Foursquare",
    imageSrc: "http://i.imgur.com/kFAk2DX.png"
}
];
    
    var contadorFecha = 1970;
    for ( x in ddData) {
       
        
        ddData[x].fecha = contadorFecha;
        contadorFecha++;
    }
```

Comment: el array objeto dentro del ciclo for no se multiplicaria ? es decir seraia bueno que el array estubiera fuera  del ciclo for y luego llenarlo con el resultado del for

Comment: Si se multiplica, pero lo uso para que se mantenga la estructura que quieres. Después está un ejemplo para modificarlo con un array existente e info.

Comment: gracias si que funciono tu codigo, para mostrara  la fecha puse la variable i en text

Comment: Si claro. Puedes acortar bastante. Que bueno que te funciono.

Comment: gracias amigo me salvaste horas de trabajo  saludos!